# Find the weights from an existing point to position a point relative to a triangle using weighted average

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, weighted-average

My understanding is I can position a point anywhere inside a triangle in 3D space using a weighted average:

```
import numpy as np
triangle = np.arange(9)
triangle.shape = (3,3)
weights = np.array([1, 0.3, 20])
point = np.average(triangle, weights=weights, axis=0)
```

Now I have a point positioned in a triangle using weighted average.
My question is how to do the inverse. If I have a triangle and I already have a point positioned inside it, can I get the weights from the relationship between the point and triangle that would let me use the weighted average to reposition the point? For example if the triangle moved and I want the point to move with it staying in the same position relative to the triangle. I realize this can be done with a barycentric calculation. I'm hoping there is a simpler way with weighted average.

Comment: Your example isn't great because the points in your "triangle" all lie in a line in 3D!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the points are stored in the rows of `triangle`, and the points don't all lie in the same line, you can use:

```
weights = np.linalg.solve(triangle.T, point)
```

Here's an example.  I'll use a modified version your `triangle` so the points are not in a line:

```
In [57]: triangle
Out[57]: 
array([[9, 1, 2],
       [3, 4, 5],
       [6, 7, 8]])
```

Using the same `weights`, compute `point` as the weighted average of the rows of `triangle`:

```
In [58]: weights
Out[58]: array([ 1. ,  0.3, 20. ])

In [59]: point = np.average(triangle, weights=weights, axis=0)

In [60]: point
Out[60]: array([6.09859155, 6.67605634, 7.67605634])
```

Now reverse the process: given `point` and `triangle`, find the weights:

```
In [61]: w = np.linalg.solve(triangle.T, point)

In [62]: w
Out[62]: array([0.04694836, 0.01408451, 0.93896714])
```

Note that `w` is normalized so its sum is 1.  If we normalize `weights`, we see that it matches `w`:

```
In [63]: weights / weights.sum()
Out[63]: array([0.04694836, 0.01408451, 0.93896714])
```

Comment: That worked great. Any chance you know a similar solution for n-gons? For example a set of 5 points.